# Append text after wordpress title

Tags: title

I would like to know is there a hook in wordpress to edit prefix and postfix of the_title in wordpress.

The code in content.php

```
the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
```

I would like to add content after the closing tag of h1.

When I use the_title hook the content is added inside the h1 tag.

Like to know how to add outside the h1 tag by using action hook (fron the plugin).

Comment: Not sure I understand, but there is a the_title filter. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title

Answer (score 1):

You can use it that way :

```
function add_suffix_to_title($title, $id = null){
    if (! is_admin()) {
        return '<h1>'.$title.'</h1> Your Suffix';
    }
    return $title;
}

add_action( 'the_title', 'add_suffix_to_title', 10, 1 );
```

And when you invoke the "the_title" function remove the h1 tag :

```
the_title();
```

I hope that would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Using get_the_title() will work for you:

```
<h1><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h1><span>YOUR CUSTOM CONTENT</span>
```

Comment: I am not asking for a solution to edit the theme file. I am interested in a action hook which will help me to do it from the plugin.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', 'YOUR CUSTOM CONTENT</h1>' );
```

Comment: Please read the question: "I would like to add content **after** the closing tag of h1." :)